# Modifying Magento Search To Match Any Keyword

Tags: php, magento

I am having some trouble with Magento admin product search! Basically I need the following:

If a product name is "Microsoft Wireless Mouse and Keyboard" and a user types into the admin manage products screen "wireless keyboard" then I want that product to appear. At the moment, unless I type two words, exactly in the order they appear (e.g "wireless mouse"), I do not get the search results.

I have tried setting Magento Catalog settings to Like, Fulltext and Combine, and all result in the exact same results. I have cleared Cache and Reindexed after changing each result, and they have not effect on how the search works.

I am running Magento 1.9.2 and running the VES Superstore theme.

Any advice on which file I can override and change the MySql query in to do what I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answered my question for me:

http://www.bigeyedeers.co.uk/better-catalog-product-search-magento/

I didn't really understand the previous answer, thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Under `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml` you will find the defined models for the global admin search.

If you go through the controller `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php` method `globalSearchAction`, you will find that Magento reads the configuration and loops on them applying the search on each module and then merging the whole result.

Since you are looking for specifically where the products are being searched, it is located in `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Search/Catalog.php`

And the query is as follows:

```
$collection = Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->getSearchCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('description')
    ->addSearchFilter($this->getQuery())
    ->setCurPage($this->getStart())
    ->setPageSize($this->getLimit())
    ->load();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. What exactly would I change to get the results I need?

Comment: You can check what the collection is building as a query, http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9464/display-a-sql-query-being-generated and then from there you can make the edits

Comment: Really sorry, could you explain it in a little more detail please, I am still getting to grips with the Magento system.

Comment: the `->addSearchFilter($this->getQuery())` falls back to your used search engine in Magento, either the default Mysql or Solr, etc. if you want to bypass this for the admin panel, I believe this is a good place to do it if you rewrite the functionality.